# TypeError while adding flask script task

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-script

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.

In the manage.py administrative module based on flask-script, I'm trying to create a new task 'create_admin' that adds a admin user .

```
@manager.command
def create_admin():
    """Creates the admin user."""
    db.session.add(User(
        email="ad@min.com",
        password="admin",
        admin=True,
        confirmed=True,
        confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    )
    db.session.commit()
```

I've added it at the end of the list as you can see:

```
manager.add_command('server', Server())
manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=_make_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
manager.add_command("urls", ShowUrls())
manager.add_command("clean", Clean())
manager.add_command("create_admin", create_admin())
```

I have a 'user' model that looks like:

```
class User(UserMixin, SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True)
    email = Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    #: The hashed password
    password = Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    first_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    active = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    is_admin = Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)


    def __init__(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, username, email=email, **kwargs)
        if password:
            self.set_password(password)
        else:
            self.password = None
```

When I try to run the new function:

```
$ python manage.py create_admin                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 57, in <module>
    manager.add_command("create_admin", create_admin())
  File "manage.py", line 46, in create_admin
    confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
(flask_mini)
```

what am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
 File "C:\envs\r2\myflaskapp\myflaskapp\models\user.py", line 31, in __init__
    db.Model.__init__(self, username=username, email=email, **kwargs)
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 525, in _declarative_constructor
    (k, cls_.__name__))
TypeError: 'admin' is an invalid keyword argument for User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User()` class takes a `username` positional argument:

```
def __init__(self, username, email, password=None, **kwargs):
```

but you don't pass one in:

```
db.session.add(User(
    email="ad@min.com",
    password="admin",
    admin=True,
    confirmed=True,
    confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
)
)
```

Pass one in as a first argument:

```
db.session.add(User(
    'admin',
    email="ad@min.com",
    password="admin",
    is_admin=True,
    confirmed=True,
    confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now()
)
)
```

I corrected `admin` to `is_admin`; you only have a `is_admin` field.

Note that you can only pass fieldvalues on to the SQLAlchemy baseclass as keyword arguments:

```
db.Model.__init__(self, username=username, email=email, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run this I get  : db.Model.__init__(self, username, email=email, **kwargs)
TypeError: _declarative_constructor() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)

Comment: @user61629: I suspect that the SQLAlchemy model doesn't take positional arguments. Pass on the arguments as keyword arguments *only*: `db.Model.__init__(self, username=username, email=email, **kwargs)`

Comment: @user61629 editing someones answer is not the right way to add further information - edit your question and add your information there, if it's too long for a comment. Incidentally, your `User` model is defined with an `is_admin` field, not `admin`.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I thought I edited my question. fixed it now.

Comment: BTW , that fixed it, thanks for pointing that out Wayne and thank you Martijin.